# Function pointer in constructor / OOP

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I have two class:

```
typedef int(*sumpointer)(int a, int b);

class A 
{
    A(sumpointer a, int b, int c)
    {
        // DO SOMETHING
    }
};

class B {
    A *a;
    B()
    {
        a = new A(sum, 5, 6);
    }
    int sum(int a, int b) {
        return (a + b);
    }
};
```

On line `a = new A(sum, 5, 6);`
I have a syntax error:

> No instance of constructor "A::A" matches the argument list argument
>   types are (int(int a, int b), int , int)

How can I fix it?

Comment: I member function cannot be used like this. Let me find a duplicate on SO.

Comment: That's not a syntax error.

Comment: There are many posts related to this subject if you search for "using member function pointer in callback". I couldn't find one that I could mark as a duplicate in good conscience. https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=using+member+function+pointer+in+callback.

Comment: Actually, i have to convert a DLL from C# to C++. In C# they using delegate, "sum" is private method of B, and it work. In C++, i try to use function pointer but i got wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use a raw function pointer to point at a non-static class method.  You need to use a pointer-to-member instead, eg:

```
class A;

class B {
    A *a;
    B();
    int sum(int val1, int val2);
};

typedef int (B::*sumpointer)(int val1, int val2);

class A {
    A(B *b, sumpointer s, int val1, int val2);
};

A::A(B *b, sumpointer s, int val1, int val2)
{
    (b->*s)(val1, val2);
}

B::B() {
    a = new A(this, &B::sum, 5, 6);
}

int B::sum(int val1, int val2) {
    return (val1 + val2);
}
```

In C++11 and later, use [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) instead:

```
#include <functional>

using sumpointer = std::function<int(int, int)>;

class A {
    A(sumpointer s, int val1, int val2);
};

class B {
    A *a;
    B();
    int sum(int val1, int val2);
};

A::A(sumpointer s, int val1, int val2)
{
    s(val1, val2);
}

B::B() {
    a = new A([this](int val1, int val2) { return this->sum(val1, val2); }, 5, 6);
    /* or:
    using std::placeholders::_1;
    using std::placeholders::_2;
    a = new A(std::bind(&B::sum, this, _1, _2), 5, 6);
    */
}

int B::sum(int val1, int val2) {
    return (val1 + val2);
}
```

Comment: Thank a lot.
I will try it.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest fix is to move `sum` out of `B`:

```
int sum(int a, int b) {
    return (a + b);
}

class B {
    A *a;
    B()
    {
        a = new A(sum, 5, 6);
    }    
};
```

Comment: Actually, this is my simplest example for my code.
"Sum" have to be a method of B, so i can't move it out.

Comment: @NguyễnVũHiếuHọc I'm answering the question you asked. If you have other code with a different problem, post the other code.